# Splitting Dataframe for Training and Validation Subsets Matching for Age and Sex

Tags: r

I have a large dataset of about 400 healthy subjects for fundamental research. I wanted to split them into a traning and a validation cohort. I thought about splitting randomly but since there's a large variation in age and more women than men included I wanted to match them to have two groups with a similar/same ratio of men and women and a similar distribution for age.

Since there is no differentiation (like patient and control) I have no groups beforehand to match them - like for the *MatchIt*-package.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The [randomizr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomizr/index.html) package may be what you're looking for. It allows for stratified randomizations, so you could randomize your sample between training and validation sets while stratifying by age and gender. You'll probably have to create age bins to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

in `randomizr`:

```
Z <- block_ra(block_var = gender)
```

this will create a vector of zeros and ones that assigns half of each gender to Z = 1.

if you want to stratify on multiple things, maybe something like

```
Z <- block_ra(block_var = paste0(gender, age_cat))
```

if you need to stratify on many variables at the same time, i'd suggest the `blockTools` package.